# How to allow users to expand javascript:OpenPopUpPage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to display a java script pop-up windows:-

```
<a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('www.bing.com');">About this</a>
```

But currently the users are not able to expand the height and width of the pop-up windows (in other word its boarder), and to display the full window they have to use scroll bar instead ?

Comment: Is this Sharepoint? There is no OpenPopUpPage in JavaScript. Read the docs for it and see if it has options.

Comment: yes it is a sharepoint site..

Comment: and its documentation specify that i can provide height and width int values , but i am not sure if  i can apply percentage and iif the int values represents number of pixels ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the next window arguments (window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight):

```
<a href='javascript:OpenPopUpPage("http://www.bing.com", null, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);'>Open Bing</a>
```

but anyway there are issues with external links in sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display popup of another website

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('http:///www.bing.com', 'yourWindowName', 'width=300,height=250');">Open Bing</a>
```

and if you want to display your own popup, use this

```
<script>
    function openWin()
    {
    myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
    myWindow.focus();
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />
```

Comment: Are you sure it is the same thing as the function? :)

Comment: my question is that i need the width and height to be expandable and not to define static numbers?

Comment: @johnG check this example http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_win_focus